# c++ quicksort pivots

Tags: algorithm, c++11, sorting, c++17, quick-sort

Is this code for quicksort using the first index as a pivot correct?
Also if I want to use the last or middle index as a pivot how would the whole code change?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void quicksort(int list[], int arraySize);
void quickSort(int list[], int first, int last);
int partition(int list[], int first, int last);

void quickSort(int list[], int arraySize) {
    quickSort(list,0, arraySize - 1);
}

void quickSort(int list[], int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int pivotIndex = partition(list, first, last);
        quickSort(list, first, pivotIndex -1); 
        quickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, last);

    }
}

int partition(int list[],int first, int last) {
    int pivot = list[first];
    int low = first + 1;
    int high = last;

    do {
        while(low <= high && list[low] <= pivot) 
            low++;
        while(low <= high && list[high] > pivot)
            high--;
        if (low < high) {
            int temp = list[low];
            list[low] = list[high];
            list[high] = temp;
        }
    } while (low <= high);

    int temp = list[high];
    list[high] = list[first];
    list[first] = temp;

    return high;
}
```

Comment: Your second question is off-topic - if you want to change the specification of your code, we can't help you.  We can just review the code you have written and make suggestions for worthwhile improvements.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm appears to be correct. When the loop terminates, either `list[high] <= pivot`, or `high == first` (and consequently also `list[high] <= pivot`).

Since you are copying the pivot value to a variable, you could simplify the code by starting with `low = first` and omitting the last swap with the pivot element in the end. You'll have to tweak the loop a bit to get it to work. This also provides you with an answer to your second question.

The declaration of `quicksort()` has different case from the definition `quickSort()`.

Since you are writing C++, not plain C, you should use `std::swap()` to swap elements.

You should use the type `std::ptrdiff_t` for array indices instead of `int`. I.e. for `first`, `last`, `pivotIndex`, etc.

Since this is C++, you could consider writing it as a template function to make it usable with types other than `int`.